# Generic method calling duplication

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following code:

```
switch (objectType)
            {
                case ObjectType.UserReview:
                    return MyMethod<UserReview>();
                case ObjectType.ProfessionalReview:
                    return MyMethod<ProfessionalReview>();
                case ObjectType.Question:
                    return MyMethod<Question>();
                case ObjectType.News:
                    return MyMethod<News>();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("objectType");
            }
```

Now I need the same code but for calling another method. Are there any options to implement it without duplication and Reflection?

Comment: Because it is the last measure for me

Comment: Reflection wouldn't work here anyway, as `ObjectType` != `Type`. Can you add some more context here?

Comment: Could you reveal what `MyMethod` does depending on which type it recieves?

Comment: @Andreas, it calls ctx.CreateObjectSet<T>.Where(...), so it generates Entity Framework query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like an ideal opportunity to [replace conditional with polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html).  Can you promote `ObjectType.UserReview` to be a class (it looks like an `enum` at the moment) and put the switch block as a polymorphic method?

Answer (score 1):

You can let `MyMethod` take an interface as an argument, e.g. `IObjectType`, like this:

```
MyMethod(IObjectType objectType)
```

That interface should contain the necessary and common method(s) that MyMethod will call, in your case:

```
interface ObjectType
{
    string GetQuery();
}
```

Then let each ObjectType implement that interface with it's own specific `CreateObjectSet<T>.Where(...)`, i.e. `UserReview`, `ProfessionalReview` and so on.

You then call `MyMethod` like this:

```
MyMethod(new UserReview()) // Ok because UserReview implements IObjectType
```

Finally it's simply a matter of letting `MyMethod` call `objectType.DoWork()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in delegates.

As far as I know, you can't partially resolve a generic delegate to a supplied method, with the generic type derived case by case, so that would mean 4 function references would need to be passed in.

```
    public static string DoStuff<T,U,V,W>(Type objectType,
        Action<T> f, Action<U> g, Action<V> h, Action<W> i)
    {
        switch (objectType)
        {
            case ObjectType.UserReview:
                return f();
            case ObjectType.ProfessionalReview:
                return g();
            case ObjectType.Question:
                return h();
            case ObjectType.News:
                return i();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("objectType");
        }
    }
```